# Is it grammatical to say: "to ask [insert name] questions?"

Tags: grammar

I know you can say:

> To make sure we had plenty of time to ask her questions, we took the
>   morning bus to her house.

How about:

> To make sure we had plenty of time to ask Mary questions, we took the
>   morning bus to her house.

Is that a valid grammatical short form of: *To make sure we had plenty of time to ask questions to Mary...*?

Comment: If it is okay to use a pronoun (her), then it is okay to use the noun it refers to (Mary).

Comment: @Tim - That depends on the kind of pronoun it is. Consider: "Jeff decided to go to **her** house." In that case, we'd say _Mary's house_, not _Mary house_. (Perhaps that's obvious to the native speaker, but it may not be obvious to the learner.)

Comment: @J.R. Quite right. The replacement has to match in case and number. I would say that is the normal inflection rule, that mine doesn't intend to override. In giving a rule of thumb,  I was trying to make it pithy.

Comment: @Tim - I started to give that same rule of thumb when I first saw this question. :^) However, the more I thought about it, the more I thought, "That seems rather obvious – I wonder if there's some underlying reason for the O.P.'s doubt." That's when I realized English uses _her_ in two different cases, which led me to my answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nothing wrong with either. The only difference is your audience. If they don't know who Mary is then her name isn't required. However, if you are talking about many different females in one instance, you may actually need **Mary** to clarify.

Answer (score 4):

If it's okay to say, *"...to ask him questions,"* then it should be okay to say, "*to ask John questions*."

I can't think of any reason a name could not be substituted for a corresponding **object** pronoun. (In your example sentence, the word *her* and an object of the verb *ask*.)

However, if the word *her* in a sentence is a *possessive* pronoun, you would need to use the possessive form of the name.

So, for example:

> The detective said, "**He** wants to ask **her** more questions."

The corresponding names can be substituted however you'd like. These are all valid variants:

> The detective said, "**Paul** wants to ask her more questions."
>   The detective said, "He wants to ask **Jane** more questions."
>   The detective said, "**Paul** wants to ask **Jane** more questions."

However, if *her* is being used as a possessive pronoun, the substitution won't work:

> **Her** questions always vex **him**.

Here, the valid variants are:

> Her questions always vex **Paul**.
>   **Jane's** questions always vex him.
>   **Jane's** questions always vex **Paul**.

I can see why this might be a little confusing for feminine pronouns in English. For masculine pronouns, English uses *his* (possesive) and *him* (object), but for feminine pronouns, English uses *her* and *her*. I'm guessing that might be why you wondered if it would be okay to make the change. After all, I if said:

> We need to make sure we leave enough time to ask **her** questions.

the sentence is ambiguous. If we are asking Mary questions, we can say:

> We need to make sure we leave enough time to ask **Mary** questions.

However, suppose we are conducting a hiring interview. Mary is a member of our company. She usually attends hiring interviews, but she is out of town this week, so she's left a sheet of paper with some questions she'd like the rest of the hiring board to ask. In that case, I would say:

> We need to make sure we leave enough time to ask **Mary's** questions.

because in that case, Mary isn't the object of the verb *ask*, she's the owner of the noun *questions*.

Answer (score 0):

Although I think both are correct I would question "To make sure we had plenty of time to ask questions to Mary...".

For me the options would be "To make sure we had plenty of time to ask questions **of** Mary..." or "To make sure we had plenty of time to  **put**  questions to Mary..."